# MS Project Baseline Start/End, Actual Start/End field

Tags: microsoft-project

I would like to know how to get rid of the hexes in the baseline and start/end fields in ms project. The expected dates and actual dates are already specified correctly in the fields just that the hexes still appear.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this is just that the columns are set to be too narrow, so then it represents the dates as hashes - #######

Not really intuitive, i know. Either manually resize the column width, or double click the column header divider, and it will auto-resize.